# Trying to run a psychopy generated experiment through portable python yields segmentation fault in Windows XP

Tags: python, windows

I've been trying to create a portable version of Psychopy that will work on any machine.  So I downloaded and installed Portable Python 2.7.6.1 and installed Psychopy 1.82.02 and pyglet 1.1.4 (a dependency that wasn't included in the psychopy install package).  Now, when running a script generated from the Psychopy builder (and slightly edited for various features) from Portable Python it works perfectly on Windows 7 and 8.1.  However, when running on Windows XP I get two errors (only one of which is really a big problem).  I get an error that it cannot import FreeTyper, and then I get a Segmentation fault in pygame parachute.

Has anyone been able to get a portable version of Psychopy running on Windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with unicode in the filename (or path). Check these two links

http://www.cogsci.nl/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/245/solved-psychopy-backend-not-working-on-xp-pc/p1

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psychopy-users/zCXtzf_RA18